# Error in creating a table in sql server (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY')

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create several tables in sql server, but I get below errors. Can you help me with those?

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuXL0.png)

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPORT 
(
    Airport_code NVARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    City NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    State NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT 
(
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    Airline NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Weekdays INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_LEG 
(
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Departure_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Scheduled_departure_time TIME NOT NULL,
    Arrival_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Scheduled_arrival_time TIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY 
        Pk_Flight_Leg (Flight_number, Leg_number),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY 
        Fk_Flight_Leg_Flight (Flight_number) REFERENCES FLIGHT (Flight_number)
           ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE FARE 
(
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Fare_code NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Restrictions NVARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY
        Pk_Fare (Flight_number, Fare_code),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Fare_Flight (Flight_number) REFERENCES FLIGHT (Flight_number)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE_TYPE 
(
    Airplane_type_name NVARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    Max_seats INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Company NVARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE 
(
    Airplane_id NVARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    Total_number_of_seats INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Airplane_type NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Airplane_Airplane_Type (Airplane_type) REFERENCES             AIRPLANE_TYPE (Airplane_type_name)
           ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE LEG_INSTANCE 
(
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Leg_instance_date Date NOT NULL,
    Number_of_available_seats INTEGER,
    Airplane_id NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Departure_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Departure_time TIME NOT NULL,
    Arrival_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Arrival_time TIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY
        Pk_Leg_Instance (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Leg_Instance_Flight_Leg (Flight_number, Leg_number)
        REFERENCES FLIGHT_LEG (Flight_number, Leg_number)
         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Leg_Instance_Airplane (Airplane_id)
        REFERENCES AIRPLANE (Airplane_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE CAN_LAND 
(
    Airplane_type_name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY
        Pk_Can_Land (Airplane_type_name, Airport_code),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Can_Land_Airplane_Type (Airplane_type_name)
        REFERENCES AIRPLANE_TYPE (Airplane_type_name)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Can_Land_Airport (Airport_code)
        REFERENCES AIRPORT (Airport_code)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE SEAT_RESERVATION 
(
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Leg_instance_date Date NOT NULL,
    Seat_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Customer_name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Customer_phone NVARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY
        Pk_Seat_Reservation (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date, Seat_number),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
        Fk_Seat_Reservation_Leg_Instance (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date)
        REFERENCES LEG_INSTANCE (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date)        
);
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 73
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 90
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 111
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: You should name the FK constraint first

Comment: For example `CONSTRAINT Pk_Flight_Leg PRIMARY KEY  (Flight_number, Leg_number),`

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in the code.

1. Use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword when you want to name the constraint.
2. Do not repeat the table name when listing the columns for primary and foreign keys.

For instance, for `FLIGHT_LEG`, the definition should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_LEG (
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Departure_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Scheduled_departure_time TIME NOT NULL,
    Arrival_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Scheduled_arrival_time TIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Flight_number, Leg_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (Flight_number) REFERENCES FLIGHT (Flight_number)
           ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would encourage you to think about synthetic keys for your table -- numeric identity columns instead of strings.  Numeric keys are more efficient in indexes and for foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You must name the **[CONSTRAINT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx)** first just after you write `CONSTRAINT` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPORT (
    Airport_code NVARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    City NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    State NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL 
);



CREATE TABLE FLIGHT (
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    Airline NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Weekdays INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);



CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_LEG (
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Departure_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Scheduled_departure_time TIME NOT NULL,
    Arrival_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Scheduled_arrival_time TIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Flight_Leg PRIMARY KEY  (Flight_number, Leg_number),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Flight_Leg_Flight FOREIGN KEY  (Flight_number)
    REFERENCES
        FLIGHT (Flight_number)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);



CREATE TABLE FARE (
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Fare_code NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Restrictions NVARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Fare PRIMARY KEY
         (Flight_number, Fare_code),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Fare_Flight FOREIGN KEY
         (Flight_number)
    REFERENCES
        FLIGHT (Flight_number)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);



CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE_TYPE (
    Airplane_type_name NVARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    Max_seats INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Company NVARCHAR(25)
);



CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE (
    Airplane_id NVARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    Total_number_of_seats INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Airplane_type NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Airplane_Airplane_Type FOREIGN KEY
         (Airplane_type)
    REFERENCES
        AIRPLANE_TYPE (Airplane_type_name)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);



CREATE TABLE LEG_INSTANCE (
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Leg_instance_date Date NOT NULL,
    Number_of_available_seats INTEGER,
    Airplane_id NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Departure_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Departure_time TIME NOT NULL,
    Arrival_airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Arrival_time TIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Leg_Instance PRIMARY KEY
         (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Leg_Instance_Flight_Leg FOREIGN KEY
         (Flight_number, Leg_number)
    REFERENCES
        FLIGHT_LEG (Flight_number, Leg_number)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Leg_Instance_Airplane FOREIGN KEY
         (Airplane_id)
    REFERENCES
        AIRPLANE (Airplane_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);



CREATE TABLE CAN_LAND (
    Airplane_type_name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Airport_code NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Can_Land PRIMARY KEY
         (Airplane_type_name, Airport_code),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Can_Land_Airplane_Type FOREIGN KEY
         (Airplane_type_name)
    REFERENCES
        AIRPLANE_TYPE (Airplane_type_name)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Can_Land_Airport FOREIGN KEY
         (Airport_code)
    REFERENCES
        AIRPORT (Airport_code)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);



CREATE TABLE SEAT_RESERVATION (
    Flight_number NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Leg_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Leg_instance_date Date NOT NULL,
    Seat_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Customer_name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Customer_phone NVARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT Pk_Seat_Reservation PRIMARY KEY
         (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date, Seat_number),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Seat_Reservation_Leg_Instance FOREIGN KEY
         (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date)
    REFERENCES
        LEG_INSTANCE (Flight_number, Leg_number, Leg_instance_date)

);
```